# CSS list ID overriding default

Tags: html, css, html-lists, custom-lists

In my `main.css` file, I have defined a style for a specific list ID (`expList`):

```
#listContainer{
  margin-top:15px;
}
#expList ul, li {
    list-style: none;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
#expList p {
    margin:0;
    display:block;
}
#expList p:hover {
    background-color:#121212;
}
#expList li {
    line-height:140%;
    text-indent:0px;
    background-position: 1px 8px;
    padding-left: 20px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
#expList .collapsed {
    background-image: url(../images/collapsed.png);
}
#expList .expanded {
background-image: url(../images/expanded.png);
}
```

This works fine and I can then call my expandable/collapsible list with custom bullets (`.png`) as follows:

```
<div id="listContainer">
  <ul id="expList">
    <li>First item
      <ul>
        <li>Item hidden in the collapsed list
etc.
```

Although I thought `#expList ul, li` would only affect list items with this custom ID, it seems it's overidden the default style, and in particular the `list-style: none` property prevents me from using default numbered/bullet lists.

How can I fix this?

Comment: What I am wondering is why you have `#expList p`- there is no reason for a `<p>` being in a `<ul>` or `<li>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Although I thought #expList ul, li would only affect list items with this custom ID,

Considering

```
#expList ul, li
```

note you have a `,` followed by `li`, this means that all `li` tags irrespective of which id or class (in this case) will be not styled in your codes..So the behaviour is as expected

try

```
#expList li{
 list-style-type:none 
}
```

The above will only apply no style type to list tags found in the `ul` tag with id `#expList`